# GPU card (Nvidia)

Tags: graphics-cards, pc, nvidia

I am looking to get an Nvidia GPU card to run personal AI software, such as Stable Diffusion. How do you determine if the GPU card does not have the mining prevention feature turned on?

Answer (score 1):

I have actually heared that Nvidia disabled that mining prevention through drivers, but if that is wrong, the cards that don't have the LHR label don't have the BIOS or driver limitations and I think that the LHR version 1.0 is fully crackable